# Unable to replicate couchDB contents in pouchDB in react-native

Tags: couchdb, react-native, pouchdb

I've created a react-native project with pouchDB set up. Have installed couchDB. Trying out the same in react native using "pouchdb-react-native". The replication is not happening. I'm getting the error 'message: "getCheckpoint rejected with", name: "unknown"'. Here is following code:
    import React, {
      Component,
    } from 'react';

```
import {
  View,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-react-native'

const localDB = new PouchDB('todo');
const remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/todo');

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Get records
    localDB.allDocs({include_docs: true})
      .then(results => {
        results.rows.map(row => {
          console.log(row.doc);
        })
      }).catch(err => alert('Err in fetching all records'));

    localDB.sync(remoteDB,
      function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        } else { 
            console.log(response); 
        } 
    });


    localDB.changes({
      live: true,
      include_docs: true
    }).on('change', () => {
        console.log("Event changed in localDB");
        this.getAllRecords();
      })
      .on('complete', () => {
        console.log("Event complete in localDB");
        this.getAllRecords();
      })
      .on('error', () => alert("Error"))
  }



  render() { 
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Example screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help on this. The package.json looks something like this:

```
"pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
"pouchdb-react-native": "^6.3.4",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.47.2",
```

What is wrong here? and how can this be debugged?

Also tried replacing the sync portion with below code:

```
const sync = localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      direction: 'from'
    });

    sync
    .on('change', pay_load => {
      console.log(" changed!: ");
    }).on('paused', info => {
      console.log("paused");
    }).on('denied', info => {
      console.log("paused");
    }).on('complete', info => {
      console.log("paused");
    }).on('active', info => {
      console.log("Active");
    }).on('error',  err => {
      console.log("error", err);
    }).catch( err => {
      console.log("Error: ",err)
    });
```

sync goes only into "paused" state.

Answer (score 1):

I get this same error when I disconnect from the internet. Everything works fine when I reconnect. Maybe troubleshoot your connection ? I am using react native. Also, you may not need pouchdb in your package.json. I just have pouchdb-react-native which drags in the correct pouchDB.

Plus your url has 127.0.0.1 in it. I assume you just used that address to mask the real address or does that address suppose to correspond with a couchDB server you have running on your dev machine. You may need to change that address to the actual address of your couchDB server such as 192.168.1.whatever. I think 127.0.0.1 on your device or simulator will look for a server on the device or simulator not on your dev machine. Hope this helps.

Warren Bell